# Implementing a Click Functionality inside a ViewPager Webview

Tags: android, webview, youtube, android-viewpager

I have a **ViewPager** with a **Youtube Embedded Webview**.

The problem is that when I click on the play button nothing happens!

I tried calling this after webView is loaded but still, video is not playing

```
yourWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-large-play-button ytp-button')[0].click(); })()");
```

and this

```
 yourWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByClassName('youtube-player')[0].click(); })()");
```

My Webview code in adapter

```
String html = "<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" style=\"border: 0; width: 100%; height: 95%; padding:0px; margin:0px\" id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/0Yi-LvnM_5M?autoplay=1"
                + "&fs=0&enablejsapi=1&showinfo=0&controls=0&autohide=1\" >\n"
                + "</iframe>\n";


        dummyWebView.clearView();
        dummyWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        dummyWebView.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Is there is any workaround?

[image]

Comment: Post you viewpager & webview fragment code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it myself by overriding onInterceptTouchEvent() to return false for that particular Video area!